# Shrink title label text of UIButton when it reaches max number of lines

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that I want resizing the text font depending on the size of the `NSString`. I want the **maximum number of lines** to be 3 and if the `NSString` length exceeds 3 lines then the **font shrinks** until all the text is shown. This is what I have so far:

```
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
```

However this code does not do as I please; the `UIButton` text contains `...` if the `NSString` exceeds 3 lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug to set the `lineBreakMode` when you want to the text to shrink.  Just remove the line that sets `lineBreakMode` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the minimumScaleFactor of the label. The default is 0.